# jquery combine event functions

Tags: jquery, function, events

instead of example:

```
$(".myfield").blur(function() {
    // validate
})
$(".myfield").keyup(function() {
    // validate
})
```

is there a way to combine these two?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Yes**

```
$(".myfield").bind('blur keyup', function(){
  // validate
});
```

Reference: [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Answer (score 6):

In case you want to validate each for itself...

```
$('.myfield').live('blur keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'blur') {
    // validate on blur
  }
  if (event.type == 'keyup') {
    // validate on keyup
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't use live as it will is depricated

Comment: Sure but in 2010 it was up to date ;) And by the way thanks for the downvote!

Comment: :) should check the date first :)

Comment: @Dan Myasnikov  "live" and "on" are not fully equivalent - see this simple sample: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffz2012/eEzwd/ -- bind is not always cutting as well

Comment: just to add - see this fiddle by Danielle to see ways to handle differences: http://jsfiddle.net/uw2bE/1/

Comment: Something like jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#price").bind('blur focus change keypress', function(){
        if(jQuery(".serverSideValidationPrice ul")!=''){
            jQuery('#price-val').css("display","none");
        }
    });
});

Answer (score 4):

use with .on() Event

```
$(document).on("keyup blur", "#myfield", function(event)
    {       
    // your code        

    });
```