# How can one bind the release of the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

In july '10, a similar question was asked.([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289298/is-it-possible-to-create-a-jquery-event-that-triggers-when-a-scrollbar-is-releas))
At that time, top answer was that it couldn't be achieved.

Anyone know how it would be possible now ?
I've seen it here : http://www.beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayA9 
When you scroll the bar, there's nothing much than the default behavior,
then when you release it the site scrolls to the nearest section top.

What's the trick here ?

All I could come up with to achieve a similar effect was to add several fixed div on the top of the site like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .fake-bar {
        position:fixed; 
        height:100%;
        width:15px;
        right:0;
        overflow-y:scroll
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <section style="height:500px">page 1</section>
    <section style="height:500px">page 2</section>
    <section style="height:500px">page 3</section>
    <section style="height:500px">page 4</section>

    <div class="fake-bar">
        <div style="height:2000px;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="fake-bar">
        <div class="invisible-handler"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and then bind the '.unvisible-handler'

But there's maybe an easier way to do that,
The B&O site doesn't seem to use stacked divs.

Anyone have a clue on how it's done ?

Comment: does this also need to take into account middle mouse scrolling and middle mouse click scrolling? why can't you just use the scroll event and detect when it stops? it should handle all three cases and any others.

Comment: @KevinB : no, actually all other events that scroll the site (up/down arrows, mousewheel, space bar, ...) return false and are handled in another way. So oGeez answer fits prefect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by capturing both mouse down and mouse up events on the window. Record the scroll top of the window when mouse goes down and then test to see if the value is different when the mouse comes up. Do whatever it is you need to do if the condition is true:

```
var initScr = 0;
$(window).on({
    'mousedown':function(){
        initScr = $(this).scrollTop();     
    }, 'mouseup':function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() !== initScr){
            console.log('change'); //Your function to go to the nearest section
        }
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n3an2/)

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm.

For some reason I thought i couldn't bind events on the scrollbar because it wasn't properly the site but the navigator.

Comment: This solution does not work on IE11, the mousedown and mouseup events won't get triggered when clicking on the scrollbar.