# JQuery same function for multiple events (ex: hover and click event)

Tags: jquery

is there any way to execute same code for different events on the page?

```
$('.class1').hover(function() {
   some_function();
});

$('.class1').click(function() {
   some_function();
});
```

instead to do something like:

```
$('.class1').click.hover(function() {
   some_function();
});
```

Comment: Reconsider your question for syntax errors, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery combine event functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279251/jquery-combine-event-functions)

Comment: These are not different elements, these are different events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is the way to go if you want to attach the event handlers at the same point in your code using the same selector, if you want to attach them at different points or using different selectors, you could always just use a named function, rather than an anonymous one:

```
function someWrappingFunction() {
   some_function();
}

$('.class1').hover(someWrappingFunction); 

$('.class1, .anotherClass').click(someWrappingFunction);
```

Comment: excellent. thank you. Also note that if you use `$(document).ready(function(){ // event handlers });`, you don't need a wrapping function. Just a function.

Answer (score 11):

Use [*bind()*](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
$('.class1').bind("click hover", function() {
   some_function();
});
```